# Ubuntu 18: eclipse fails while attempting to load SWT libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

I am running latest eclipse, and when I open WindowBuilder JTable's model's diaglog, I get this error:

> Blockquote
> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Unspecified error [Error while starting AWT] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
> /media/Backup/eclipse/java-2021-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/333/0/.cp/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /media/Backup/eclipse/java-2021-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/333/0/.cp/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so) no swt-awt-gtk in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib no swt-awt in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/lib/libjawt.so: version` SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so)
> Can't load library: /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt-gtk.so
> Can't load library: /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt.so
> /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /home/abusous2000/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-awt-gtk-4946r21.so)
> )
> at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4919)
> at org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT.new_Frame(SWT_AWT.java:168)
> at swingintegration.example.EmbeddedSwingComposite2.createFrame(EmbeddedSwingComposite2.java:338)
> at swingintegration.example.EmbeddedSwingComposite2.populate(EmbeddedSwingComposite2.java:196)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.models.table.TableModelDialog.createDialogArea(TableModelDialog.java:147)
> at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
> at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.property.editor.models.table.TableModelPropertyEditor.openDialog(TableModelPropertyEditor.java:81)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.TextDialogPropertyEditor$1.onClick(TextDialogPropertyEditor.java:35)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.editor.presentation.ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl$4.handleEvent(ButtonPropertyEditorPresentationImpl.java:124)

It should be noted that

- I get this error even if I run JDK 11, 15, or 17. Even I tried Oracle JDK as some have suggested
- I linked the JNI files locally be executing
  ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
- I installed latest jni by executing
  sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-4-jni libswt-gtk-4-java
- I tested this on Ubuntu 16, & got the same error

Really I am at a lose. This is leads me to believe this is an OS issue

Answer (score 0):

Once I downgraded my environment to Eclipse Luna, WindowBuilder 1.9.0, & to Oracle 8 JDK, it did work. Therefore it is related to latest eclipse & JDK. I hope this helps someone else who ran into a similar issue. Anyhow, I am curious to know why this failed! I like to use latest eclipse whenever I can.